# Meaning of "The finalize method is never invoked more than once by a JVM for any given object." in case of Object Resurrection?

Tags: java, finalizer

As per Java Doc:

The finalize method is never invoked more than once by a Java virtual machine for any given object.

1. Can the above policy help to make an object immortal? If I resurrect an object one time from finalize() method then will that object become immortal, because finalize() method cannot be called on that object second time by JVM?

OR

2. If the object become eligible for GC again (suppose the another reference pointing to resurrected object becomes eligible for GC) then next time JVM will delete the object without calling the finalize() method for that object?

I have tried to verify it by some sample code and assuming the second one is correct, but need confirmation for my understanding.

Comment: It's number 2. The object will be garbage-collected without a call to its finalize() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per ernest_k 
It's number 2. The object will be garbage-collected without a call to its finalize() method.

Adding my sample code to complete this answer, which I created to verify.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

class Immortal {

    // making it public and non-fianl to modify from outside
    public static Set<Immortal> immortals = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Running finalize for " + this);
        immortals.add(this); // Resurrect the object by creating a new reference
    }
}

public class ObjectResurrection {

    public static void callGC() {
        // call garbage collection
        System.gc();

        // wait for some time to give chance to run garbage collection thread
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Immortal immortal1 = new Immortal();
        Immortal immortal2 = new Immortal();

        // print objects when they are alive.
        System.out.println("immortal1 = " + immortal1);
        System.out.println("immortal2 = " + immortal2);

        // print immortal set
        System.out.println("immortal set = " + Immortal.immortals);

        // make all objects garbage collectable
        immortal1 = null;
        immortal2 = null;

        callGC();

        // now objects will be null
        System.out.println("immortal1 = " + immortal1);
        System.out.println("immortal2 = " + immortal2);

        // but stays in immortal set
        System.out.println("immortal set = " + Immortal.immortals);

        // remove all objects from immortal set, and make them again eligible for GC
        Immortal.immortals.clear();

        callGC();

        // again print the immortal set
        // this time set will be empty, and those 2 objects will be destroyed by Garbage
        // Collection,
        // but this time they will not call finalize, because it is already called
        // you can notice no output from finalize method in the output this time
        System.out.println("immortal set = " + Immortal.immortals);
    }

}
```

Output of Above Program (on my machine):

```
immortal1 = effective.java.item7.finalizer6.Immortal@70dea4e
immortal2 = effective.java.item7.finalizer6.Immortal@5c647e05
immortal set = []
Running finalize for effective.java.item7.finalizer6.Immortal@5c647e05
Running finalize for effective.java.item7.finalizer6.Immortal@70dea4e
immortal1 = null
immortal2 = null
immortal set = [effective.java.item7.finalizer6.Immortal@5c647e05, effective.java.item7.finalizer6.Immortal@70dea4e]
immortal set = []
```